# SPLIT_TO_TABLE using a variable/Parameter in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a variable

```
declare VAR1 varchar;
let VAR1 := '001,002,sam1';
```

I need to get the out put as below by pasing the variable into the select statement.

```
001
002
sam1

SQL statement tried:
select tbl1.value
from table(split_to_table(:VAR1, ',')) as tbl1;
```

I keep getting the error unsupported datatype `VAR1`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
set VAR1 = '001,002,sam1';
select tbl1.value from table(split_to_table($VAR1, ',')) as tbl1;
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to use this in a Stored Procedure (for future reference, this sort of relevant information would have been helpful in your original question), then this code should work:

```
BEGIN
    let VAR1 := '001,002,sam1';
    select tbl1.value 
    from table(split_to_table(:VAR1, ',')) as tbl1;
END;
```

Obviously, as written, this code is pretty useless as you're not capturing the result of the SELECT - but I assume you are going to incorporate it into a larger piece of code?

Comment: Yes, but it's not giving the expected results. It says "Syntax error: unexpected SELECT"  This is what my query looks like   DECLARE VAR1 VARCHAR;
LET VAR1 := ‘001,002,sam1’;
SELECT TBL1.VALUE FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(:VAR1, ‘,’));

Comment: I am trying to do this a stored procedure.

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you saying it gives an error but then show a completely different set of statements than the ones I gave you? My statements work when run as-is in a worksheet. Your statements seem to be using the sort of syntax that you would use within an anonymous SQL block - but as you haven't provided the full syntax that type of structure would require, I'm assuming that's not what you are trying to use?

Comment: I will be using this in a where clause. My VAR1 is an input parameter from SSRS report into the stored procedure.