Snowflake How to solve when there is a need for unrelated subquery in select?
Database: Snowflake
DBT to generate the SQL model.
I have a column in a table that contains the list of product ids owned by user.
Table: users



user_id
name




u1
user 1


u2
user 2



Table: products



product_id
product_name




1
A


2
B


3
C



Table: user_attributes



date
user_id
product_list




2024-12-01
u1
1,2,3


2024-12-01
u2
2,3,4


2024-12-02
u1
2,3


2024-12-02
u2
2,3,4



Now, I want to return the product names owned by user.
Expected output:



date
user_id
product_names




2024-12-01
u1
A,B,C


2024-12-01
u2
B,C,D



I tried this but getting an error

Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

select 
    *, product_list,
    (select listagg(product_name, ',') 
     from products 
     where product_id in (select value 
                          from table(split_to_table(product_list, ',')))) as product_names
from 
    users_attributes ua
left join 
    users u on ua.user_id = u.user_id

When I tried by hardcoding the product_list in subquery, it works executes but of course that is not what I want.
select 
    *, product_list,
    (select listagg(product_name, ',') 
     from products 
     where product_id in (select value 
                          from table(split_to_table('1,2', ',')))) as product_names
from 
    users u
left join 
    user_attributes ua on u.user_id = ua.user_id


Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Have you considered using dynamic SQL? Construnct your statement as a string, append your product_list, and execute the whole thing.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-construct-at-runtime

Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77755800/split-to-table-using-a-variable-parameter-in-snowflake


LATERAL split_to_table to split the product lists into rows.
Then we get a distinct list of product ids based on date and user_id
And then those are joined iwth product table to get product names.
LISTAGG will then convert the rows to comma separated values.

Query
WITH expanded_products AS (
    SELECT
        ua.date,
        ua.user_id,
        TO_NUMBER(split_value.value) AS product_id 
    FROM 
        user_attributes ua,
        LATERAL split_to_table(ua.product_list, ',') AS split_value 
)
SELECT
    ep.date,
    ep.user_id,
    LISTAGG(p.product_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p.product_name) AS product_names
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT date, user_id, product_id FROM expanded_products) ep
JOIN 
    products p ON p.product_id = ep.product_id 
GROUP BY
    ep.date, ep.user_id
ORDER BY
    ep.date, ep.user_id;

Output


I tried this out with a CTE and found a way to get you the result you needed. Basically, I unzipped that product list column, joined the attributes to the products and users, then zipped it back up again.
WITH split_attributes as (
   SELECT date,
     user_id,
     value as product_id
   FROM user_attributes, LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(product_list, ','))
SELECT
   users.user_id,
   users.name,
   split_attributes.date,
   LISTAGG(products.product_name,',') AS product_names
FROM users
LEFT JOIN split_attributes
   ON split_attributes.user_id = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN products
   ON split_attributes.product_id = products.product_id
GROUP BY split_attributes.date, users.user_id, users.user_id;


A slightly improved and readable approach similar to using UDF. Product ID enriched using the UDF. As the comments mentioned, storing a list of items in an array is better than a comma-separated string.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION product_name_mapping(product_list string)
  RETURNS STRING
  AS
  $$
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(product_name, ',')
    FROM products
    WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(CAST(product_id AS STRING)::variant, STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(product_list, ','))
  $$
  ;


select 
    date,
    user_id,
    product_name_mapping(product_list) as product_names
from user_attributes ua;


